# Como declarar o resultado final como variavel em uma estrutura repita no Visualg?

Tags: portugol, visualg

Estou usando o Visualg como início para ter uma ideia da lógica de programação. Acontece que eu criei um algoritmo com a estrutura `repita` junto com a estrutura `se` que conta do número que o usuário escolheu até aonde ele quer e de quantos em quantos números pula. Entretanto, é que eu queria que caso sobrasse um número no final, que esse número que ele chegou fosse declarado como a variável N4. Como eu faço isso?

Sei que eu posso ter explicado meio embaraçado, então vou dar um exemplo:
Vamos supor que o usuário entre no programa e pegue os seguintes números na ordem: 0, 15 e 7. O programa vai contar de 0 até 14 apenas, mas eu queria mostrar para o usuário que contou até N4 (o 14 no caso) no final. Como eu faço isso?

```
algoritmo "Contador"
var
N1,N2,N3,N4 : inteiro
inicio
   Escreval ("--------------------------------------------------------------")
   Escreval ("                  CONTADOR DE NUMEROS                      ")
   Escreval ("--------------------------------------------------------------")
   Escreval ("              SÓ VALE NUMEROS INTEIROS!!                   ")
   Escreval ("--------------------------------------------------------------")
   Escreval ("Me fale um numero para eu começar o contador: ")
   Leia (N1)
   Escreval ("Me fale um numero para eu terminar esse contador:  ")
   Leia (N2)
   Escreval ("Me fale um numero para eu ir pulando entre o começo e fim")
   Leia (N3)
   Escreval ("--------------------------------------------------------------")
   Escreval ("VOU ADIVINHAR SE ESSES NUMEROS SÃO PAR OU IMPAR PRIMEIRAMENTE")
   Se (N1 % 2 = 0) entao
      Escreval ("O numero ",N1," é par!! Acertei? É LÓGICO!!")
   senao
      Escreval ("O numero ",N1," é impar!! Acertei? É LÓGICO!!")
   FimSe
   Se (N2 % 2 = 0) entao
      Escreval ("O numero ",N2," é par!! Acertei? É LOGICO!!")
   senao
      Escreval ("O numero ",N2," é impar!! Acertei? É LOGICO!!")
   Fimse
   Se (N3 % 2 = 0) entao
      Escreval ("O numero ",N3," é par!! Acertei? É LOGICO!!")
   senao
      Escreval ("O numero ",N3," é impar!! Acertei? É LOGICO!!")
   FimSe
   Escreval ("--------------------------------------------------------------")
   Se (N1 > N2) entao
      Enquanto (N2 <= N1) faca
         Escreval (N1)
         N1 <- N1 - N3
   FimEnquanto
   senao
      Enquanto (N2 >= N1) faca
         Escreval (N1)
         N1 <- N1 + N3
   FimEnquanto
   Fimse
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: O que te impede de colocar um `N4 <- N1` após o `Fimse`?

Comment: Na hora não pensei nisso.Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque após o `Fimse`:

```
N4 <- N1
Escreval ("Número no final ", N4)
```